# "Golder standard" RNA-seq datasets for neurodegenerative diseases

Tags: neuroscience

What's your favorite and/or "gold standard" RNA-seq datasets for neurodegenerative diseases?

I come from the field of computational cancer genomics where there are some datasets that are well-known as "high-quality" ones in cancer. I want to benchmark some of the computational tools I'm currently developing on RNA-seq datasets for neurodegenerative diseases: I want to make sure I can identify known regulators with the tools I am testing. Therefore, I am looking for high-quality RNA-seq datasets for neurodegenerative diseases. Any advice on where to find such datasets?

Comment: This question might be a better fit for bio.SE - @AliceD?